# GraphQL Edge Endpoint is not rendering custom Error Pages

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

On JSS 21.1 with SXA, the Next.js custom error pages functionality isn't working. [I've configured it per the documentation.](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/generate-a-custom-static-error-page-959639.html)

I've tracked it down to the GraphQL query.

Request:

```
query ErrorPagesQuery($siteName: String!, $language: String!) {
  site {
    siteInfo(site: $siteName) {
      errorHandling(language: $language) {
        notFoundPage {
          rendered
        }
        notFoundPagePath
        serverErrorPage {
          rendered
        }
        serverErrorPagePath
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteInfo": {
        "errorHandling": {
          "notFoundPage": null,
          "notFoundPagePath": "/404-page",
          "serverErrorPage": null,
          "serverErrorPagePath": "/500-page"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So it looks like it is resolving the custom error page paths but not able to render them.

Answer (score 1):

On a hunch I tried renaming the pages and discovered that if you remove all spaces from the page item name it works. There must be a bug in the page item resolving logic somewhere.
I also noticed that you can't simply call the page 404 or 500, these seem to be reserved page names in Next.js. I called mine 404Page and 500Page.